# Getting error on executing a procedure having dyinamic sql

Tags: sql, oracle, toad, ora-06550

This the procedure I have written in Toad (Oracle 19c):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ITMS.SP_ADD_FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT_AUTO (
    P_TABLE_NAME    VARCHAR2,
    P_COLUMN_NAME   VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE   'ALTER TABLE '
                     || P_TABLE_NAME
                     || ' ADD CONSTRAINT '
                     || P_TABLE_NAME
                     || '_'
                     || SUBSTR(P_COLUMN_NAME,1, INSTR(P_COLUMN_NAME,'_ID')-1)
                     || '_FK FOREIGN KEY ('
                     || P_COLUMN_NAME
                     || ') REFERENCES '
                     || SUBSTR(P_COLUMN_NAME,1, INSTR(P_COLUMN_NAME,'_ID')-1)
                     || '(ID)';
END;
```

I have created the above procedure which is executing fine in toad for Oracle with query:

```sql
EXEC SP_ADD_FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT_AUTO('DTMS_BA_VOLUME_DISCOUNT_DETAILS','REF_BUSINESS_ASSOCIATE_ID')
```

where I have written all query in single line.

but if I execute like this :

```sql
EXEC SP_ADD_FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT_AUTO('DTMS_BA_VOLUME_DISCOUNT_DETAILS',
   'REF_BUSINESS_ASSOCIATE_ID') `
```

Where I have written some part of query in next line. I am getting error -

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 76:  
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:
```

Can you please tell why I am getting this?

Comment: This would be a Toad issue, not an Oracle one. Your client is apparently treating a line break as the end of a command and adding a command separator `;` at that point when it submits it to Oracle. It has nothing to do with your stored procedure or dynamic SQL inside it. Column 76 is the point between the two parameters in your EXEC string.

Comment: I think someone edited out your line break. If my comment doesn't resolve your issue and you want to keep the question open you may want to reedit it and put the line break back in where you had it originally.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm Please be **very** careful when making edits to questions that you do not inadvertently make changes that invalidate the question. Your first [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76836216/2) removed some whitespace from one of the commands that was actually the cause of the issue and then the question did not make sense.

Comment: You can test this behaviour with any procedure call. For example, what happens if you split `exec dbms_output.put_line('Hello, world')` onto two lines? If you hit the same issue then you can stop worrying about dynamic SQL etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an SQL or Oracle issue or anything to do with the procedure or dynamic SQL, it is an issue that the client application is behaving exactly as documented when it sends a command to the database but it does not meet your expectation of how it should behave.

From the [SQL*Plus documentation on the `EXECUTE` command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqpug/EXECUTE.html#GUID-A64F29C8-B5C7-426D-82E9-A8E85763F3D6):

> ### Syntax
>
> ```sql
> EXEC[UTE] statement
> ```
>
> where `statement` represents a PL/SQL statement.
>
> Executes a single PL/SQL statement. The `EXECUTE` command is often useful when you want to execute a PL/SQL statement that references a stored procedure. For more information on PL/SQL, see your Oracle Database PL/SQL Language Reference.
>
> ### Usage
>
> If your `EXECUTE` command cannot fit on one line because of the PL/SQL statement, use the SQL*Plus continuation character (a hyphen).
>
> The length of the command and the PL/SQL statement cannot exceed the length defined by `SET LINESIZE`.

As the documentation implies; the `EXECUTE` command expects your `statement` to fit onto a single line so when it encounters a line break it expects `statement` to be a complete PL/SQL statement and will send that statement to the database for it to parse. The database is returning the appropriate error because it is being sent the command:

```sql
EXEC SP_ADD_FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT_AUTO('DTMS_BA_VOLUME_DISCOUNT_DETAILS',
```

and the command is syntactically invalid as it has an open bracket but no closing bracket.

Everything is behaving exactly as the documentation states it should.

As the documentation states, if you do want to have a command spanning multiple lines then you need to use the SQL*Plus continuation character (a hyphen).